# Can ADD and LDUR be used to accomplish the same thing?

Tags: assembly, arm, addition

Do these two assembly commands result in the same machine action? If not, what are the differences?

```
// X6 is the base address of an integer array, X10 is a temporary register
ADD X10, X6, XZR
LDUR X10, [X6, #0]
```

Comment: One is a calculation, one loads data from memory. They're quite different.

Comment: So in the first command, would X10 be the address of A[0]? Or the value stored there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is an add, `X10=X6+0` (or effectivly a register copy in this case), the second is a load from memory, using X6 as a pointer with zero offest (so your index [0] array value).

In ARM, arithmetic operations are performed on the values in the general purpose registers (using the same register bank to hold results), and accesses to memory use one (or more) general purpose registers to hold the data, and another general purpose register as a pointer.

This is known as a load/store architecture. If you're more familiar with a different type of architecture, the instruction set may appear confusing to start with.